# GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS file not accessible

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I'm trying to use the Google Speech API using PHP client library. Following the documentation I have created the service key, copied it to the vm where my application sits and set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env variable. However when I try to use the service, I'm getting an error saying the credentials file does not exist, even though I can access the file and it's contents by copying the exact same path as shown in the error message.

So to sum it up, the env variable is being correctly set, the path it's being set to is correct, but for some reason the service can't see the file. Any ideas please?

Comment: Permissions maybe? Does your application run under a different account than you log in with?

Comment: Need much more information. Can you list the paths, echo the output of the env variable, list the file permissions? Also, how is the PHP application running? If it is running under something like nginx then how is nginx being run?

Comment: I don't think it's permissions, it happens even if I change them to full open. Also tried it two different ways, by uploading the credentials file directly from host as well as creating it from a template with ansible during the provisioning of the vm, both results were the same.

Comment: @AndyShinn The application is running as vagrant user and as the same user I can access the file from the console just fine. As I already said, the paths are correct, I know that because I can just copy and paste the absolute path shown in the error message and run cat on it and it shows the correct file contents. Can't show you the outputs unfortunately for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be caused by the path in the env variable being surrounded with quotes.